# Load_Csv_data from GCS to Bigquery

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I have 100 CSV files in my GCS bucket.I want to upload all the CSV files in Bigquery table.

I have tried to use Autodetect= True but the problem is that, for few of the columns, it's giving wrong field types and got failed. Can you guys suggest me any turnaround?

Answer (score 1):

For that problem, the problem is in data within the files itself. If say 99 files have , lets say 3 columns (string, int, string) and if one file has (string, int, int) or something different, in that case GBQ wont be able to detect a common schema and will error out.

Try doing 50 files first and see if you still face the same issue. Then go down to 25, then to 10 files. Basically you will have to weed out the file that is problem maker here and either remove that file or fix it.
(Try to look into GBQ error in detail, it might give you more details to spot the bad file.)

OR

If you are okay with making everything ingested as STRING values as a start: You can disable auto detect, and make whatever number of fields you know as STRING, just for first load ingestion and once you have all data in initial GBQ table then u can figure out what you want to do with it or how to proceed or what is really wrong with data. (Once you have all data in a table you have more leverage on what transform you can do on it to fix it.)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried specifying a schema for you table ?

You can do the ingestion with a schema for your columns.

For example, if you have a field called "toto" as String in your schema, it will works for String value from files but also with Int value for example.
Bigquery knows the type is String for this field and if a Int value is given, BigQuery will convert it as String.